# How to connect to database and stream data with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, api, phpmyadmin

I'm building a C# program that is going to connect to a game developer's API in order to get and store data for later use. Currently, I'm working on connecting to my database as first order of business.

I assumed that something along the lines of this would work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connString = "Server=myIP;Database=myDatabase;Uid=myUser;Pwd=myPass;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE id=1";
            try
            {

                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["text"].ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

I have allowed my computer's IP to connect to the database by editing cPanel. When I run the program I just get a blank cmd prompt. What could this be?

Also, if anyone has any knowledge on the process of streaming data from this API to the database through a variable of some sort, I would love to know. I'm a noob to C#. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? Does the query return any rows? If not, it will just fall through to the `Console.Readline()` and wait for input.

Comment: I'm not that experienced in C#. How do you use a debugger?

Comment: You can start at [Debugging in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx). Or try YouTube and search for `visual studio debugging tutorial`.

Comment: When I run with debug I get this: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Could not find specified column in results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to access a column 'text' which doesn't exist in the result set.

If 'text' is a column is the table 'user' you would need to update your query to explicitly include it:

```
SELECT username, text FROM user WHERE id=1
```

Alternatively, try outputting values from the username column:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader["username"].ToString());
```

**Further Reading**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommandmembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareaderitem

Note: I'm not familiar with the MySqlClient, if this doesn't help just let me know.

Additionally, you might consider wrapping your reading of the result set in a try/catch and logging any errors to make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: Thanks for making me realize that I put 

Console.WriteLine(reader["text"].ToString());. Stupid me, it works great now!